# Javascript value undefined when passing from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, undefined

UPDATE: Thank you everyone who helped out. I hope the myriad of solutions on here can serve as a reference for anyone who is facing similar difficulties.

I am reading from a text file with PHP and I need to pass the string into JS for manipulation. I tried the more direct way of placing the PHP into my external JS file, but that didn't work so I'm resorting to using an empty div container. However, in JS I'm still getting an undefined value. The file reads correctly into the div value, it just won't pass to my external javascript file.

HTML:

```
<?php
    $world = file_get_contents('http://url.com/testworld.txt');
    //echo $world;
?>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="game" width="650" height="366" style="border: 2px solid black;"></canvas>
        <br />
        <h1> Currently in development.</h1>
        <br />
        <div id="world" value="<?php echo $world; ?>" />
    </body>

</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var world = document.getElementById('world').value;

document.write(world);
```

If there is a way to make just pulling the variable from the PHP in an external javascript file work, I would prefer to do that.

Comment: So I tried using a hidden input and a textarea. I'm still getting the Chrome console error "cannot read property 'value' (or 'innerHTML') of null" on the line where I define the JS variable. This is so bizarre.

Comment: Please include the *HTML AS SEEN BY THE BROWSER* and *PLEASE INCLUDE THE RELEVANT JAVASCRIPT* :-) The error is caused by `someNullExpression.innerHTML` which is *can not* be the result of the code posted above as there is no `innerHTML`.

Comment: I meant to say, it's giving my 'innerHTML' as null when I tried one of the solutions below that required me to change from 'value' to 'innerHTML'. The code above is LITERALLY everything.

Comment: @ZachWulf When you changed to innerHTML did you also change your div tag?

Comment: Yes...for all of these solutions, I've changed the appropriate attribute that corresponds to the element. The closest I've got was that HTML5 solution by patbolo, but then on the page it just spits out "undefined". It's almost as if the variable in my JS file has absolutely no idea where my PHP file is and that it has to pull from it.

Comment: @Zach Wulf Make sure you are using `$.ready` (or `init()` here) because `getElementById(x)` is only *guaranteed* after the DOM is complete (although it will often work if used *after* the element in question is created *assuming it is closed correctly* which the *HTML AS SEEN BY THE BROWSER WOULD SHOW*). In any case, there are multiple issues. Work on one, and use good troubleshooting techniques, not guesses. My previous comment should give a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to pass data from PHP -> JS without resorting to hiding it inside the DOM.
The trick is the json_encode() function - it will convert php strings, array, etc into a valid javascript format.
See your example below, fixed up:

```
<?php
    $world = file_get_contents('http://url.com/testworld.txt');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //World is defined here, and accessible to the javascript that runs on the page
        var world = <?=json_encode($world)?>;
    </script>
    <canvas id="game" width="650" height="366" style="border: 2px solid black;"></canvas>
    <br />
    <h1> Currently in development.</h1>
    <br />
</body>
```

---

I'm pretty sure your troubles are occurring because of the way that scoping of variables works in javascript. This simple example *must* work for you:

```
<?php
    $foo = "\"Hello world!\"";
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var foo = <?=json_encode($foo)?>;
        alert("The value of foo is: " + foo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So in the context of the inline script, the `foo` variable is present. Perhaps if your code were to look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Load the game world, and pass to the javascript lib
    var world = <?=json_encode($world)?>;
    loadWorld(world);
</script>
```

then you wouldn't have to worry about scoping so much?

Comment: I'm getting a "world is not defined" in my Javascript file

Comment: Try defining `var world;` in your javascript file, and just using `world = ...` in the HTML.

Comment: That's somewhat better, but it just spits out "undefined" onto the page where the contents of the file should go.

Comment: I've appended some more - try this simple example, it should at least demonstrate proof that you can pass data from PHP -> JS.

Comment: Hey, thanks MrTrick, I really appreciate your continued help. The contents of my PHP file are successfully passing to JS when the script is in the same file, but for the purposes of what I'm trying to do, I need it to pass on to my external file. I have never had a problem with things like this before.

Comment: So I have a .txt file being read by PHP (successfully) that just contains a bunch of random letters, nothing fancy. I need to be able to read this into my main JS file to break up the string and work with it from there. Anything in the same file, whether it is a hidden input tag or an inline script will always output fine. The only problem is when I try to pass the contents into my external JS file.

Comment: I tried the aformentioned steps with JSON encoding. The alert worked perfectly fine, it spit out all the text. Next I tried passing through function to my external file, just like the example. "Cannot read property 'value' of null.

Comment: WAIT! That worked! I will mark your solution, thank you so much. Like you said, the issue was with variable scoping.

Answer (score 1):

`value` has a special meaning on DOM Elements (it refers to the value of textboxes, etc.). Instead, you might use an [HTML5 Data Attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) such as `data-value`, and then examine it using `document.getElementById('world').getAttribute('data-value');`.

However, a better approach would be to use a hidden input, such as

```
<input type="hidden" id="world" value="<?php echo $world; ?>" />
```

and then leave your script as is.

Answer (score 1):

Another way :
In your php

```
<div id="world" data-world="<?php echo $world; ?>" />
```

In your JS:

```
$('#world').attr('data-world');
```

Also you may want to make sure the value of $world is properly escaped for being used as an html attribute

Comment: It just spits out the word "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to have a value attribute to a div. Instead of a div use a hidden textarea element and put file content inside that using something like:

```
<textarea id="fileContent" style="display:none"><?php echo $world; ?></textarea>
```

and then in JS:

```
document.getElementById('fileContent').value;
```

Will return the text area content

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but it might be that the 2 `$world` variables to be in different scopes. Try with:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="game" width="650" height="366" style="border: 2px solid black;"></canvas>
        <br />
        <h1> Currently in development.</h1>
        <br />
        <div id="world" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('http://url.com/testworld.txt'); ?>" />
    </body>

</html>
```

and see if it works

Comment: Thanks, but it's still saying it can't read the property 'value' of null in my JS file. It's almost as if my external file has absolutely no idea that it's being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<div id="world" value="<?php echo $world; ?>" />
```

to:

```
<div id="world"><?php echo $world; ?></div>
```

and change:

```
getElementById('world').value;
```

to:

```
getElementById('world').innerHTML;
```

If you need to you can add a style of `display: none;` to the div to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying value in div tag, you should specify that value in hidden input field.this is a better approach
like this

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="game" width="650" height="366" style="border: 2px solid black;"></canvas>
    <br />
    <h1> Currently in development.</h1>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="world" id="world" value="<?php echo $world;?>"/>         
</body>

</html>
```

you should also specify form tag too. by specifying form tag, you can have more ways to access element using javascript.

if you want to use div then it should be like this ..

```
<div id="world"><?php echo $world;?></div>
```

in js you can access $world by this code ..

```
var world = document.getElementById('world').innerHTML;
```